# How to include a javascript file with Sinatra using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, sinatra

Note: This works fine when I don't use ajax.  I have the same behavior with slim and haml. Here is the [source](http://ididitmyway.herokuapp.com/past/2011/2/27/ajax_in_sinatra/) for using ajax with Sinatra

I am trying to run some javascript in a page created using sinatra while using ajax.  See sample using haml below.  This works fine.  Is there any way I can use a file containing javascript, instead of the alert statement below, i.e,. use alert.js

```
@@testjavascript
%p #{@time}
:javascript
  alert("Hello world");
```

The following is just to give additional background on an alternative approach.
When I try to use the script statement, the script gets embedded within my html element.  Here is what I am doing:

I am using right.js.  I add this event handler:

```
"#testscript".onClick(function(event) {
  event.stop();
  $('msg').load("/testscript");
});
```

and the haml:

```
@@testscript
%p #{@time}
%script src="about.js"
```

when I do that the p element and the script element are embedded with the div.

```
<div id="msg">
  <p>The time is 2014-01-05 12:21:39 +0800</p>
  <script>
    src="about.js"
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your output of

```
<script>
  src="about.js"
</script>
```

isn't actually what you likely want. What you really want is probably something more like this:

```
<script src="about.js" />
```

In order to get something like that, you need to add the `src` attribute as an attribute in the HAML, like this:

```
%p #{@time}
%script{:src => "about.js"}
```

The other issue is with your jquery. It should be `$('#msg').load`, with the # sign, because that is the id of the div.

Comment: I tried using the attribute for src, but get the same result in html.  What is the difference (in html) between <script>..</script> and </script  />?   The javascript syntax is actually correct - it is supported by right.js.  Not sure if I can create a sample of something like jsfiddle